# Accounting database model

Tags: database-design, erd

Need to build a service with an internal wallet function.
Here is a simple use-case diagram:
[image: Wallet use-case diagram]

I have made a DB model
[image]

But I don't like it for the next reasons

- No guarantee there will be only 1 sub-type record.
- No guarantee there will be at least 1 sub-type record.
- No clear way to display the detailed historical list of entries.

So, the question is - how to organize the DB model right? I am ready to accept even the most radical solutions, like anchor modeling or something. Just want to know the ideal accounting DB model. My favorite DB is PostgreSQL, but in general, it doesn't matter.

Here is my `accounting_entry` main entity implementation - https://gist.github.com/dilame/dcb55112833d0ad6579a08fd573592da

All the other entities supposed to be sub-type of `accounting_entry` as shown in the ER diagram.

Comment: Are you aware of the Data Model Ressource Book? Vol 1 has a full accounting schema (among a LOT of other things) and I consider it my go to resource for pretty much every enterprise related data schema question and problem I encounter.

Comment: Also: How much do you need in terms of legality? There are country specific requirements, at times.